# Open multiple React apps constantly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I'll explain what I need to do and what I'm doing with it. My ask is for an advice on how to improve this process.

I'm a tutor in a ReactJs course and I need to review my tutees apps. So, I've trying 2 things. First I was cloning the repo on a random folder in my pc, then installed the node_modules from the app and the ran the app. Then I deleted the whole folder and continue with the next one (time consuming). Then I started to leave the folders and when I had to review anything new from the same student I did a fetch/pull to obtain the new commits from that repo, but, I don't know why, somehow it started draining my ram and my pc was so slow (I have 20 apps to review, so 20 repos, 20 node_modules, not running at the same time, I kill the server before reviewing the next one, but still..)

I'm not really sure if I'm explaining myself. I could review only the code, but I really prefer to run each app to give feedback, make sure to review the console.. actually see how the app is looking like. So please, if you have any advice for me to improve this process I would really appreciate it. I believe I'm doing it all wrong and there are ways to do this better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have the 20 apps open at the same time? (even if they weren't running)  I think what was killing your RAM was having too many open editors at the same time. Also I don't think there's a better solution, since you want to actual see the app running, you need to install and start each one, unless you decided to only check code and in some final projects actually running the code.

Comment: I only ran one at a time, but I had the main folder containing all apps opened in the vs code

Comment: I would suggest you to automate this with writing a simple selenium or pyautogui script with python.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your student/s push build or dist folder in repo.
Create one node-express boilerplate to run react static files.
As you have bundled code in repo, just copy that bundled code (build/dist folder) in node-express destination.

It will eliminate your work for installing node_modules for every project.